# Creating TThread does not enter my Create() method

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm using Delphi Rio.  I have created a thread class.

```
type
  TThreadManager = class(TThread)
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TThreadManager.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);     // thread-ul va fi creat, dar nu va rula
                               // pentru a-l rula, folosim "Resume" (sau "Execute")
  FreeOnTerminate := True;     // thread-ul va fi distrus automat cand termina
  Priority        := tpNormal; // prioritatea thread-ului este minima
  <- creating internal objects here
  fIsSetupOk      := False;
end;
```

However (this) constructor is not used when I create the thread in the application. No debug breakpoints are available. And also no objects are created.

```
threadManager := TThreadManager.Create;
threadManager.Setup(dmMain.ibSessionMain);
threadManager.Resume;
```

Because of not entering this constructor, an AV is raised when accessing the objects.

Any hints?

Sure, I can create the objects elsewhere (into the setup) but that is not what I want.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. The error is probably in a part that you don't show. Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: Rightclick on `TThreadManager` and choose "Find declaration" - do you really see the code you expect or is it a different one? Also try `TheUnitName.TThreadManager.Create` to make it unambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TThread` has its own parameter-less `Create()` constructor. You should declare yours as `reintroduce` to hide the existing one, eg:

```pascal
type
  TThreadManager = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  end;
```

A better option would be to call `Setup()` inside of `Create()` itself, and set `CreateSuspended=False`. This way, there is no ambiguity over which constructor to call, and the thread will start running automatically after `Setup()` is finished, eg:

```pascal
type
  TThreadManager = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create(Session: TIB_Session); reintroduce;
  end;

constructor TThreadManager.Create(Session: TIB_Session);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Priority := tpNormal;
  <- creating internal objects here
  fIsSetupOk := False;
  Setup(Session);
end;

threadManager := TThreadManager.Create(dmMain.ibSessionMain);
```

Alternatively, you can rename your constructor to something more meaningful, eg:

```pascal
type
  TThreadManager = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor CreateAndSetup(Session: TIB_Session);
  end;

constructor TThreadManager.CreateAndSetup(Session: TIB_Session);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Priority := tpNormal;
  <- creating internal objects here
  fIsSetupOk := False;
  Setup(Session);
end;

threadManager := TThreadManager.CreateAndSetup(dmMain.ibSessionMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem in **my code** after I use suggestion 2 from remy.
After creating the method as suggested (adding TIB_SESSION as parameter) I have found that the method is not usable because is declared in the **protected** section not public.
After putting in the correct section all is fine.
Many tks

Comment: Then the code you showed us is wrong. The concept of a MCVE is that you show us what you executed yourself. Since that code did not have `protected` in its class definition you misleaded everyone.

Comment: Indeed. however I have showed what I think is enough. I have already admitted my fault, and I put the correct answer for anyone else see this or have similar problems.

Comment: Concept on [mcve] is not that you show what you think is enough, but to create project with that reduced code and that you test it to see whether problem exists. Adding that information as answer is not as helpful to others as you may think. It merely serves as reminder that you didn't make proper mcve and why it is important to do that before asking questions.

Comment: You would need to make your custom constructor public only if `TThreadManager` is implemented in a different unit than it it used in. Which was not made clear in your question.